# Сихнронизация в WEB припложении(Java Spring)

Tags: java, веб-программирование, spring, синхронизация

Здравствуйте, разрабатываю, грубо говоря, систему для автоматического проведения олимпиад и вот столкнулся с проблемой синхронизации, точнее не знаю как лучше это осуществить... вот пример:

#### Entity

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name= "increment", strategy= "increment")
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "login", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String login;

    @Column(name = "password", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 150, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "count_true_answers", nullable = false)
    private long countTrueAnswers;

    @Column(name = "count_questions", nullable = false)
    private long countQuestions;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_group", nullable = false)
    private Group group;

    @Transient
    private List<Question> questionsUser;

    @Transient
    private Queue<Log> logsUser = new LinkedList<>();

    public User(){

    }

    @Builder
    public User(String login, String password, String name, long countTrueAnswers, long countQuestions, Group group) {
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
        this.name = name;
        this.countTrueAnswers = countTrueAnswers;
        this.countQuestions = countQuestions;
        this.group = group;
    }

    public void addLog(Log log){
        logsUser.add(log);
    }

    public void removeQuestion(String title){
        for (Question question : questionsUser) {
            if(question.getTitle().equals(title)){
                questionsUser.remove(question);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

#### Component для проведения олимпиады

```
@Component
public class OlympiadImpl implements Olympiad {

    @Autowired
    private QuestionsService questionsService;
    @Autowired
    private UsersService usersService;

    private User currentUser;

    public void startOlympiad(String login, String password){
        currentUser = usersService.getUserByLoginAndPassword(login, password);
        currentUser.setQuestionsUser(questionsService.getQuestions());
    }

    public String getStatisticUser() {
        return String.valueOf(currentUser.getCountTrueAnswers() + "/" + currentUser.getCountQuestions());
    }

    public List<Question> getQuestions() {
        return currentUser.getQuestionsUser();
    }

    public Question getQuestion(String title){
        for (Question question : currentUser.getQuestionsUser()) {
            if(question.getTitle().equals(title)){
                return question;
            }
        }
        return currentUser.getQuestionsUser().get(0);
    }

    public Queue<Log> getLogsOfRunningTest(){
        return currentUser.getLogsUser();
    }

    public ResultChecking checkTask(String nameQuestion, String 
        // Проверка задания
    }


    private void delQuestion(String title){
        currentUser.removeQuestion(title);
    }

}
```

Думаю сервис слой и дао приводить нет смысла, ибо там все очевидно. Выше расположенный код дает возможность проводить олимпиаду только для одного пользователя(добавлять логи, удалять вопрос только для пользователя а не из Бд, если он правильно на него ответил), но хотелось бы, чтобы была возможность для многих. Собственно мысль у меня сделать Map пользователей, хранить cookie пользователей и при обращениии к кому-то методу олимпиады добавлять cookie пользователя(логин или имя), и уже вытаскивать из Map этого пользователя и проводить с ним операцию. но мне кажется такой подход не совсем удачный, куча дополнительныйх расходов как по времени так и по памяти. Пробовал scope prototype указывать, но он каждый раз создает новый класс олимпиады... Может быть есть какие-либо инструменты для этого у Spring или java или быть может мой подход тоже окажется подходящим в этой ситуации?

Comment: ThreadLocal Вам не поможет?

Comment: Не помог, может быть я что-то не так использовал, но при установке вопросов порльзователю и при установки пользователя для прохождения олимпиады, но потом когда нужно получить впоросы пользователя, получаю NullPointer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для начала стоит отказаться от велосипедостроения и отдать управление пользовательскими сессиями Spring Security.

Далее. У вас `OlympiadImpl` в данный момент сильно завязан на внутреннее состояние, причем именно на текущего пользователя в лице `currentUser`. Логично сделать такой компонент сессионным.

- Если вы используете Spring MVC - задайте ему `@Scope(WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION)`. Тогда для каждого активного пользователя у вас в Spring-е будет свой экземпляр `OlympiadImpl`.
- Если же Spring MVC  у вас нет (а, например, JAX-RS), то можно написать свой собственный сессионный custom scope на куках, атрибутах сессии и `ThreadLocal`-ах.

---

> куча дополнительных расходов как по времени так и по памяти

Серьезно? Spring у вас уже создает дикое количество промежуточных слоев и абстракций, не стоит бояться создавать структуры данных, которые нужны вам для решения бизнес-задачи.